# Reading the date from textbox as a string and converting it into as Date

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, momentjs, datejs

I am reading the date from textbox by using javascript and trying to convert it as Date object.But **my problem is date is converting as month and month is converting as date when converting the string to date.**

Example:
03/12/2014 the value in the textbox

Actual Output:
03 as March,
12 as date (Its wrong)

Expected Output:
03 as date
12 as December (I am expecting)

While converting this string to date by using following snippet

```
var startTime = document.getElementById("meeting:startTime");
date.js
var stringToDate_startTime=new Date(Date.parse(startTime.value,"dd/mm/yy"));
moment.js
var date1=moment(startTime.value).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

In the above even i have used date.js and moment.js files also.But those also did not solve my problem.Please can anyone help me out to get rid out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
var from = startTime.value.split("/");
var newDate = newDate(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);
```

... assuming time included ...

```
var date_only = startTime.value.split("");
var from = date_only[0].split("/");
var newDate = newDate(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);
```

Comment: my text box contains time also.This is my textbox value "03/12/2014 23:05"

Comment: Adjusted to accomodate the time being entered.  Time can be accessed in date_only[1] ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of an implementation of the Date.parse() method that accepts two arguments. You can view the Mozilla Date.parse() method description here [Date.parse() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

It might be worth looking at the question/answer of this question for some more information: [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse)

The next best option would be to split the date using String.split() and to rearrange the date parts

```
var dateStr = '03/12/2014 23:05';
var newDateStr = null;
var dateParts = dateStr.split('/');
if (dateParts.length == 3) {
   var day = dateParts[0];
   var month = dateParts[1];
   var yearAndTime = dateParts[2];

   // Rearrange the month and day and rejoin the date "12/03/2014 23:05"
   newDateStr = [ month, day, yearAndTime].join('/');
} else {
   throw new Error('Date not in the expected format.');
}

var date = new Date(newDateStr);   // JS Engine will parse the string automagically

alert(date);
```

This isn't the most elegant solution, but hopefully that helps.

Comment: This assumes that you create a variable named "dateStr".

Comment: If i use second method i will not able to get the time.My text box contains time also.

Comment: This is my textbox value "03/12/2014 23:05"

Comment: Do you know for certain that the date will always be in that format? I've updated the code to reflect handling the time.